# Show that two discrete spaces are homeomorphic iff they have the same cardinality

Tags: general-topology

I have the following question:

Show that two discrete spaces are homeomorphic iff they have the same cardinality:

I have tried the following:

Let $f: (X, \mathcal{T}_{discrete}) \to (Y, \mathcal{T}_{discrete})$

$(\Rightarrow )$

As we have that the topology is the discrete then in particular each $\{x\} \in X$ is an open set, as we have that $f$ in a homeomorphism then $\{f(x)\} \in Y$ is an open set, this allows to conclude that both spaces have the same cardinality.

$(\Leftarrow )$

Let suppose that both spaces have the same cardinality, since both spaces are discrete then we have that each $\{x\} \in X$ is an open set and analogous each $\{y\} \in Y$ is an open set.

If we define the function $f$ as
$$f: (X, \mathcal{T}_{discrete}) \to (Y, \mathcal{T}_{discrete}) \text{ as } x_i \to y_i i \in |X|$$

then we have that is a bijective map, and for the affirmation that I made before $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. So we have that both spaces are homeomorphic.

---

Is correct what I have done?, thank you

Answer (score 4):

If both sides have discrete topology, then any map is continuous. So as long as you have a bijection it is a homeomorphism. Thus this is true iff the underlying sets have same cardinality.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Every homeomorphism is a bijection and every function whose domain considered with discrete topology is automatically continuous irrespective of the topology in the codomain .